# Passing Looped Array Values From PHP to JavaScript & JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to make a search box in my web application, and I used ajax post to make a request to my server. My question is:

Is it possible to send looped array values from PHP to my JavaScript?
I want to get all of the results from my server.

CLIENT SIDE: Ajax POST request

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "searchPlaces.php",
       data: { searchInput: form.searchTxtId.value },
       success: function (result)
       {
            // Get the search result
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

SERVER SIDE (after retrieving the post from ajax, and making queries):

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query))
{
   $resultName = $result['name'];
   $resultAddress = $result['address'];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [array from php to JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823516/array-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: You can't mix-and-match HTML and JavaScript comments that way; if you're putting a place-holder comment in your JavaScript, it should probably be a JavaScript comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$results = array();
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query)) {
   $results[] = $result;
}
echo json_encode(array('results' => $results));
```

In your `success` callback you can then iterate over `result.results` which contains an object with the column names from your query as attributes.

```
success: function(result) {
    $.each(results, function(i, row) {
        console.log(row.name, row.address);
    })
}
```

It is also advisable to use `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax({...});` arguments to avoid unnecessary guessing of the response type.

In case you have more columns in the SQL resultset than you want to forward to the client, you could add a custom array in the loop:

```
$results[] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'address' => $row['address']);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can you can return a json string :

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       dataType: 'json', // return type is json ;
       url: "searchPlaces.php",
       data: { searchInput: form.searchTxtId.value },
       success: function (result)
       {
            $.each($result,function(index, value){
                 // use params
            } 
       }
   });
```

and on your php side you use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)